# Find maximum product subarray

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, dynamic-programming, sub-array

We need to Find the contiguous subarray within an array (containing at least one number) which has the largest product and return an integer corresponding to the maximum product possible.
I found this code to solve the same :

```
int maxProduct(const vector<int> &A)
{
    int n = A.size();
    vector<int> maxarray(n);
    vector<int> minarray(n);
    maxarray[0] = A[0];
    minarray[0] = A[0];
    int result = A[0];
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++){
        if(A[i]>0){
            maxarray[i] = max(A[i],maxarray[i-1]*A[i]);
            minarray[i] = min(A[i],minarray[i-1]*A[i]);
        }else{
            maxarray[i] = max(A[i],minarray[i-1]*A[i]);
            minarray[i] = min(A[i],maxarray[i-1]*A[i]);
        }
        result = max(result,maxarray[i]);
    }

    return result;
}
```

What is the need to maintain a minarray ? And can you please explain these lines :

```
if(A[i]>0){
            maxarray[i] = max(A[i],maxarray[i-1]*A[i]);
            minarray[i] = min(A[i],minarray[i-1]*A[i]);
        }else{
            maxarray[i] = max(A[i],minarray[i-1]*A[i]);
            minarray[i] = min(A[i],maxarray[i-1]*A[i]);
        }
```

Why are we updating the maxarray and minarray as done in the above lines of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`minarray`'s purpose is to handle negative numbers.

`{-1, 42, -2}` would return 42 without `minarray`.

```
if (A[i]>0){
    maxarray[i] = max(A[i], maxarray[i-1]*A[i]);
    minarray[i] = min(A[i], minarray[i-1]*A[i]);
} else {
    maxarray[i] = max(A[i], minarray[i-1]*A[i]);
    minarray[i] = min(A[i], maxarray[i-1]*A[i]);
}
```

When `A[i]` is positive, `prev*A[i]` doesn't change of sign.
Other case to handle: when previous value is 0

So maximum product until index `i` is

- `A[i]` if `maxarray[i-1]` is 0 (or negative with initialization)
- `maxarray[i-1]*A[i]` else.

`std::max` simplifies the condition.

In the same way, minimum product (largest negative number) would be `std::min(A[i], minarray[i-1] * A[i])`.

When A[i] is negative, `prev*A[i]` does change of sign.
so maximum has to take previous minimum

`maxarray[i] = max(A[i], minarray[i-1] * A[i]);`.

When `A[i] == 0`, both maximum and minimum would be `0`. (both branch would be fine for it).